# Rails Association Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am just wondering how I am suppose to build a bookManager has follow. The models his has follow

```
|-------------|1---------*|-------------|
| Customer    |           | BookManager |
|-------------|           |-------------|
| ID          |           | ID          |
| First       |           | customer_id |
| Last        |           | isDeleted   |
| Email       |           | isVisible   |
| Password    |           | description |
|-------------|           |-------------|
```

The association is as follow

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
# RELATIONSHIP
    has_many :book_managers
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :book_managers, allow_destroy: :true
    attr_accessible :admin, :first_name, :last_name, :middle_name, :email, :email_confirmation, :password, :password_confirmation, :image, :book_managers_attributes,  :locale
end

class BookManager < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer
    attr_accessible :customer_id, :visible, :description
end
```

The form is like this
Customer#edit view

```
  <h3>Book</h3>
  <div><%= render 'book_managers/form' %></div>
```

BookManagers/Forms

```
<%= form_for(@book_manager) do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <%= f.check_box :visible %>
    <%= f.label :visible %>
  </fieldset>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

and this is the big prize puzzle. The controllers
At the moment i have nothing in the BookManager controller because its the caller that tend to have the data information. But i am really confused on the customer Controller.

What i want is to associate and fill up the BookManager with customer and its attribute.
here what i have for now.

CustomerController

```
        @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])

#       @book_manager = BookManager.new
#       bm = @customer.book_managers.build
#       bm.books.build

        @book_manager = @customer.book_managers.build
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something called fields_for to build child models

```
<%= form_for @customer do |customer_form| %>
  First name: <%= customer_form.text_field :first_name %>
  Last name : <%= customer_form.text_field :last_name %>
  <%= fields_for @book_manager do |book_manager_fields| %>
    Admin?  : <%= book_manager_fields.check_box :admin %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Something of this nature.  So when you submit it will post all the data together on your parameter.

`@customer.save` would also save book managers